# Trying to solve a variant of longest substring, but getting stuck in a while loop

Tags: python, substring

So I have been trying to solve a practice problem where given a string, return the longest unique substring that occurs within that string. for example, if the string was "aab" the output of my function should be "ab" .

Below is my attempted solution, when I run it the function never ends, so I looked at it step by step and noticed that my function never progresses past the first while loop, but I am unsure why.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yv2p.png)

Comment: Do you mean the longes substring of unique characters?

Comment: you should post your code, so that we can copy it to find the bug, not screenshot it.

Comment: [Images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your question about substring without repeat? I try your code, it stuck because data.get(s[j], -1) keep being 0,so your j keep being 1 and stuck in the loop. You can debug it and change your way to find repeat char. Here is a code may give you some help.

```
def LongestSubstring(s: str):
i = 0
if len(s) == 0:
    return None
while i < len(s):
    sub_size = len(s) - i
    start = 0
    while start < (len(s) - sub_size + 1):
        sub = s[start:(start + sub_size)]
        start = start + 1
        for k in sub:
            counts = sub.count(k)
            if counts > 1:
                break
            if k == sub[len(sub) - 2]:
                return sub
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In spending some time retyping your code and then testing it, I tried to debug various points in the code but I seemed to keep running in circles trying to see where the function was not correctly checking for the longest substring.  So, to provide an alternate train of thought, following is a refactored version of the function along with a test string to validate the new train of thought.

In these types of exercises, usually what needs to be done is to attempt to find the longest string of unique characters, starting at the first position of the string, then redo the test from the second position of the string, then the third position, and so on until the last character position is reached.  All the while a check is made for the longest unique string on each pass and a check and save of the longest found substring.  With that, following is a refactored version of the code as food for thought.

```
def get_longest(s):
    longest = 0
    longestSubStr = ""
    i = 0
    
    while True:
        x = range(i, len(s) - 1)
        work = s[i]
        for n in x:
            if s[n] != s[n + 1]:            # Check where non-unique characters are found and build a substring
                work = work + s[n + 1]
            else:
                break

        if len(longestSubStr) < len(work):  # If the current test substring is longer than the previous substring, update the newest longest substring
            longestSubStr = work
            print("Current longest substring is", longestSubStr)

        i += 1                              # Keep incrementing the starting point in the substring until the righthand position is reached

        if i == len(s):
            break

    return longestSubStr

s = "abbcdffgciuyentuyydoiy"                # With this test string, the longest substring would be "fgciuyentuy"
print(get_longest(s))
```

Running this test in the terminal yielded the following output.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/CheckString$ python3 Longest.py 
Current longest substring is ab
Current longest substring is bcdf
Current longest substring is fgciuyentuy
fgciuyentuy
```

This is just one of many possible routes to your solution, so evaluate it in the frame of reference of your problem and assignment.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient approach to solving the problem in linear time complexity would be to use a FIFO queue as a sliding window to the string of characters as you iterate through the characters, and shrink the window until the current character is no longer a duplicate in the window. To efficiently look up if the current character is in the window, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) so that both a lookup and a window shrinking can be done in constant average time complexity:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_longest_unique_substring(s):
    window = OrderedDict()
    longest_end = longest_size = 0
    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        while char in window: # if the current character is in the window
            window.popitem(last=False) # shrink the sliding window
        window[char] = True # add the current character to the sliding window
        if (size := len(window)) > longest_size:
            longest_end = index + 1
            longest_size = size
    return s[longest_end - longest_size: longest_end]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/6UWdM4